# Django Progress Bar (with celery not working)

Tags: django, redis, celery

So, I'm making this twitter tweets analyzer for my portfolio website, and I'd  figure why not make a progress bar since it takes a while to load and parse the tweets (around 200). How hard could it be?

My google search led me to this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BbPswIqn2VI) using Celery + redis + [celery-progress](https://github.com/czue/celery-progress). Okay watched the video then i read the [github](https://eeinte.ch/stream/progress-bar-django-using-celery/) of celery-progress + two([1](https://buildwithdjango.com/blog/post/celery-progress-bars/),  [2](https://eeinte.ch/stream/progress-bar-django-using-celery/)) articles regarding the process. seems straightforward.

​

so i set up `celery.py`

```
import os

from celery import Celery

# set the default Django settings module for the 'celery' program.
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'my_proj.settings')

app = Celery('my_proj')

# Using a string here means the worker doesn't have to serialize
# the configuration object to child processes.
# - namespace='CELERY' means all celery-related configuration keys
#   should have a `CELERY_` prefix.
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

# Load task modules from all registered Django app configs.
app.autodiscover_tasks()


@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print(f'Request: {self.request!r}')
```

and set up  the `settings.py` also

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    .......
    'django_celery_results',
    # Celery apps
    'celery',
    'celery_progress'
]
.
.
.
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis url'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis url'
```

also set up the `init.py`

```
# This will make sure the app is always imported when
# Django starts so that shared_task will use this app.
from .celery import app as celery_app

__all__ = ('celery_app',)
```

and finally i made a test_task in a [tasks.py](https://tasks.py)

```
from celery import shared_task
from celery_progress.backend import ProgressRecorder
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import tweepy

import time
@shared_task(bind=True)
def test_task(self):
    print("Task Started")
    progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
    for i in range(5):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(i)
        progress_recorder.set_progress(i+1, 5, description="Processing...")
    print("End")
    return "Completed"
```

The guy in the video also used [django-celery-results](https://pypi.org/project/django-celery-results/). But for some reason i always get a NO NULL exception. So i just used the redis as the backend as with the other guides.

My 1st issue. The broker.  The video uses heroku redis. For some reason i can't connect at all (testing on my local host). Found out the heroku redis only worked on the heroku platform itself. So i switched to Redis To Go.

```
[tasks]
  . main_page.tasks.get_tweets
  . main_page.tasks.test_task
  . portfolio_website.celery.debug_task

[2021-04-17 23:19:36,358: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://redistogo:**@soapfish.redistogo.com:11025//
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,486: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,712: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-6] child process 19360 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,724: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-2] child process 14712 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,727: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-3] child process 10332 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,730: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-1] child process 2716 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,740: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-7] child process 9084 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,749: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-4] child process 19752 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,760: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-8] child process 22720 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:36,765: INFO/SpawnPoolWorker-5] child process 5888 calling self.run()
[2021-04-17 23:19:38,187: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
```

so far so good.  I can connect to redis (Redis to Go). Time to test in the front end.

Okay first try. Just complete crashed. there seems to be the error on the backend. so I'll just disable the celery back-end for now. (I don't really need to store the results anyways).

```
TypeError at /twitter_stock/

sequence item 1: expected a bytes-like object, NoneType foun
```

The task does start but progress bar doesn't appear at all. Also there's this attribute error.

```
95a539f9-c105-4180-961f-02f223809314
Task Started
0
1
2
3
4
End
posted
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

HTML

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center pt-3">
    <div class='progress-wrapper'>
      <div id='progress-bar' class='progress-bar' style="background-color: #68a9ef; width: 0%;">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div id="progress-bar-message">Waiting for your tweet...</div>
  </div>

  <script src="{% static 'celery_progress/celery_progress.js' %}"></script>

  {% if task_id %}
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Progress Bar (JQuery)
    $(function () {
        var progressUrl = "{% url 'celery_progress:task_status' task_id %}";
        CeleryProgressBar.initProgressBar(progressUrl, {})
    });
</script>
{% endif %}
```

views (oversimplified)

```
def twitter_stock(request):
    task = test_task.delay()
    task_id = task.task_id
    .
    .
    .
    print(task.id)
        return render(request,{'task_id': task_id})
```

I'm using Jquery CDN. I'm considering testing Amazon SQS as well. But now I'm stuck. I really don;t know what to do. If someone there actually knows an alternative (there has to be an easier way to do this) or knows how to make this work, I would really appreciate it. Thank you for bearing the long post.

TLDR:Tried to make a progressbar using Celery + celery-progress + Redis. didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As I was facing the same issue of

```
AttributeError: 'DisabledBackend' object has no attribute '_get_task_meta_for'
```

and I wasn't able to view progress even in my django-admin because no record was storing so I found out that it is needed to define this line in your project settings

```
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "django-db"
```

this solved my issue i hope this will solve your too